# For looping an arrays char length and placing text per char

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make it where every time the for loop is called in the dom it  will create an "_" for every char in that array per word, but I'm having trouble whenever I call it. I either get "underscore is not a function" or "there is an error with the for."

```
        let wordGuesses = ["woody", "buzz", "sid", "bopee", "yog"];
        let lettersGuessed = [];
        let guessesRemain = 10;
        let randomWord = [Math.floor(Math.random()*wordGuesses.length)];

            let underScore = 
            for (let i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++){
            wordGuesses.charAt(i) = " _ ";
        };

        // let wordLetter = function (letter){
        //  for (let i = 0; i < letter.length; i++){
        //      letter.charAt(i);
        //      console.log(letter.charAt(i));
        //  }
        // }


        //for (let i = 0; i < wordGuesses.length; i++)

        // window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
        //  let userGuess = event.key;
        //  console.log(userGuess);
        //  lettersGuessed.push(userGuess);
        //  console.log(lettersGuessed);
        // })

        document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = underScore;


<!-- Paste the part of the code that shows the problem. (Please indent 4 spaces.) -->


            let underScore = 
            for (let i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++){
            wordGuesses.charAt(i) = " _ ";
        };
```

Comment: `let randomWord = [Math.floor(Math.random()*wordGuesses.length)]` is not doing what you think it is. It's returning a single element array. You want `let randomWord = wordGuesses[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordGuesses.length)]`.

Comment: `wordGuesses.charAt(i) = " _ ";` isn't valid either. You'll need to use a `==` or use something like the `.replace()` method. You'll also want to use `randomWord.` instead of `wordGuesses.`.

Comment: Thanks for debugging and the tips guys